# Automapper ProjectTo<>() issue when using NotMapped/Computed property in Source to map in destination

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, automapper

I am getting the error only when I am using ProjectTo, I could not understand the underlying issue. (Automapper version am using 4.2.1.0)
    **"The specified type member 'Tags' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. 
            Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."**
    We could do this manipulation in DTO as well, but I should stick to doing the manipulation in entity side only. 
Do let me know the ways or work around I could handle this without upgrading the version. TIA
I want the computed value of Tags property of entity needs to be mapped to the Tags property of the DTO, but this works fine when I am doing the normal way.

Source/destination types

```
public class Template : IEntity<int>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string _Tags { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<string> Tags
        {
            get { return _Tags == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(_Tags); }
            set { _Tags = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); }
        }       
    }
```

Entity Config

```
internal sealed class TemplateConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Template>
    {
        public TemplateConfig()
        {
            Ignore(x => x.Tags);
            HasKey(x => x.Id)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("Template");
                    m.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
                    m.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
                    m.Property(x => x._Tags).HasColumnName("Tags");
                });
        }
    }
```

Destination DTO:

```
public class Template
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping configuration

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Template, DTO.Template>();               

Mapper.CreateMap<DTO.Template, Template>(); 


//These are just for information, but getting error only when using ProjectTo. (Ignore about the OData thing)




 public virtual async Task<IQueryable<TDto>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<TDto> query)
            {
                try
                {
                    var expands = query.GetExpandedPropertyNames();
                    //Assume the collection has the data from db
                    var test = Collection.ToList();
                    //getting the exception here
                    return await Collection.ProjectTo<TDto>(null, expands).AsTask();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

    //Controller method
    public override async Task<IQueryable<Template>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Template> query)
            {
                try
                {
                   List<Template> result = (await base.Get(query)).ToList();

                    return result.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `.ProjectTo<>(...)` is building the select statement for you in SQL. As `.Tags` maps between your objects, it is being included in the select statement, and then entity framework is complaining that it can't do that (because of the `NotMapped` attribute).

Instead of using `ProjectTo<>(...)` you could just use a normal `.ToList()` and then use `.Select(Mapper.Map<TDto>)` or `Mapper.Map<List<TDto>>(list)`.

That should work, as entity framework will populate your Tags field from the string field, and automapper can do the map ok.

```
public virtual async Task<IQueryable<TDto>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<TDto> query)      
{
    try
    {
        var expands = query.GetExpandedPropertyNames();

        //Assume the collection has the data from db
        var test = Collection.ToList();

        var entities = expands.ToList();

        // you can either use .Select to project using LINQ
        var dtos = await entities.Select(Mapper.Map<TDto>).AsTask();

        // or you can use Mapper.Map to a list of entities.
        dtos = await Mapper.Map<List<TDto>>(entities).AsTask();

        return dtos;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // side note, don't throw ex, you'll lose the stack trace
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, using Mapper.Map it works, but my problem is only with ProjectTo. I can not do away with this implementation, I need to stick to ProjectTo only maybe with some tweaks is fine. Does this kind of scenario not supported by Automapper at all, or had it been fixed in any recent release or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not without duplicating the logic into the Map. You could set up the Map to read from the `_Tags` property and then deserialize it there. Automapper can't do this automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I solved the issue by adding a ToList before using ProjectTo though unsure if that is the right fix. (Converting it to list, takes a effect on performance though) I guess there is no issue with the auto mapper in dealing with a computed value, Json serialization or a NotMapped property.

Something like this worked.

                `var test = Collection.ToList().AsQueryable();
                return await test.ProjectTo<TDto>(null, expands).AsTask();`

Comment: Yes, that's essentially my original answer. Glad you got it working.

Comment: @Ixalln Yeah exactly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing the ignore in the MappingConfiguration? I can't quite tell which direction you're having issues with, but something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Template, DTO.Template>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Tags, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

Comment: Yeah, I did try Ignore but in that case, I don't get the data in Tags. It is just an empty list. I get issue only when I use ProjectTo, it works fine other ways, with the same Mapping Configuration (without using Ignore too)